# Serializing, integer without libaries , getting weird results

Tags: c++

I have an integer and I want to serialize it to binary file. I dont care about being cross platform.

I am doing the following:

```
std::ofstream f;
f.open(path, std::ios::binary);
int n = 200;
f.write((char*)&n, sizeof(int));
f.close()
```

Then after I open the file again using ifstream and read all its contents into a vector of chars, I do the following to get back the integer:

```
char* ptr = avector.data();
int n = *ptr;
ptr += sizeof(int);
```

This seems to only work IF n <= 127. when n > 127 as in this example 'n' gets a weird value instead of 200.

Comment: `*ptr` will only yield results from (-128, +127) when `ptr` is a pointer to char.

Comment: You can view any object as an array of `char`, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Since you don't care about your code being cross platform, try it on some other platforms. Maybe you'll find one where it works.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz like an old Cray?

Comment: @user4581301 Exactly. It's admittedly code that will work on some platforms and not on others. On this one, it works for `n <= 127`. The OP doesn't even tell us what platform he's using.

Comment: Obvious `char` is obvious.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Is your advice for fixing a software bug to find a different platform where the code behaves as expected? I'm assuming I'm not understanding your comment correctly.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No. My advice for fixing a software bug is to modify the code so that it is guaranteed to work. But the OP doesn't care if his code works on some platforms and not others. It's hard to qualify this as a bug if the code is intended not to work on some platforms and there exists some platforms it works on. We have rules for what you're allowed to do to produce portable code that works on all platforms that support C++. Once you're outside of that, it's hard to know what the rules are, especially if you don't even know what platform you're coding on.

Answer (score 6):

In this code:

```
char* ptr = avector.data();
int n = *ptr;
```

you are converting one byte to `int` dereferencing `char` pointer. What you need instead is to copy data:

```
char* ptr = avector.data();
int n = 0;
memcpy( &n, ptr, sizeof(n) );
```

Or:

```
char* ptr = avector.data();
int n = 0;
std::copy(ptr, ptr+sizeof(n), (char*)&n);
```

You should be aware that this is not portable solution.

What you *can't* do is:

```
char* ptr = avector.data();
int n = *(int*)ptr;
```

Although it might look sensible, and will compile, is actually quite popular and may even appear to work, it violates something called the *Strict Aliasing Rules*. You are allowed to look at an object as-if it were a `char[]`, but not the other way around. The copy is required here, regardless of portability.

Comment: or just `int n = *(int*)ptr;`

Comment: @kerrytazi might work, but violates Strict Aliasing so Undefined Behaviour .

Comment: @kerrytazi [Strict aliasing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) may allow you to look at anything as-if it were bytes, it does not let you look at bytes as-if they were something else. You have to `memcpy` in this case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The OP just wants code that happens to work on his platform. I'm guessing he wants it to work for his platform's full range of valid `int` values, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Doesn't matter, the cast violates strict aliasing, period. A copy is required here. (Loads of programmers get this wrong.) `std::copy` would be better than `memcpy` though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit surprisingly enough, there is not enough code in the snippet to say with 100% certainty there is a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: I actually think Slava that it would be good if you put this as a caveat in your answer please because people are going to keep suggesting the broken alternative in comments

Comment: @SergeyA How so? A sequence of bytes delivered to the program as a `char` array is being reinterpreted via an `int*` and dereferenced. That is textbook wrong. What's the context that permits this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit we do not know what is the object type actually contained in `avector.data()`. Could be that it is placed-new int :)

Comment: @SergeyA _"Then after I open the file again using ifstream and read all its contents into a vector of chars,"_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I said in the snippet :), and I meant it in the purest technical term, just to illustrate the point of strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @SergeyA Troll :P

Comment: @SergeyA Correct me if I'm wrong but, without a cast, that vector _must_ contain `char` otherwise you can't initialise the `char*` from its `data()`?

Comment: Wow look at that horrendous diff rendering on my revision 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the static type of vector would be, indeed `vector<char>`. However, `vector<char> vec(4); new (vec.data()) int(0); int i = *(int*)vec.data()` will be well-defined.

Comment: Anyone using placement `new` probably isn't asking this question. If they are, they've gotten way too far ahead of themselves.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit good suggestion, thanks for doing it for me, was away, sometimes you have to do boring stuff like work :)

Comment: @SergeyA Now I'm wondering what happens when the vector tries to keep doing things with the memory you've "stolen"! Probably not much owing to the trivial types involved.

Comment: @Slava Yeah no worries. As it happens, this particular topic is close to my heart (I keep seeing the broken approach in projects -.-) so my pleasure!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes, you might want to avoid sorting this vector :), but basically, this is alternative to `std::unique_ptr[]`. I was just highlighting the fact that this is permitted.

Comment: @SergeyA Well I meant even just its destructor. If its specialisation for built-in types avoids bothering with individual element destructor then you're probably okay, unless the vector spec itself lays on its own "get yer dirty mitts off" rules that go beyond the basics of object lifetime.

Comment: @SergeyA the fact that OP increases `ptr` suggests that there would be different data in that vector, so I do not think this would be a solution.